How do you get the body from a reqwest::Request?
I need to send a multipart request using reqwest = { version = "0.12.9", features = ["json", "multipart"] } I have constructed the request like this
let payload = serde_json::to_string(&document.metadata).unwrap();

    let mut metadata_headers = HeaderMap::new();
    metadata_headers.insert(
        CONTENT_TYPE,
        HeaderValue::from_str("application/json").unwrap(),
    );
    let metadata_part = Part::text(json!(payload).to_string())
        .headers(metadata_headers)
        .file_name("metadata");

    let mut file_headers = HeaderMap::new();
    file_headers.insert(
        CONTENT_TYPE,
        HeaderValue::from_str("application/octet-stream").unwrap(),
    );
    let byte_array = document.content.to_vec();
    let file_form_part = Part::bytes(byte_array.clone())
        .headers(file_headers)
        .file_name(document.metadata.id_doc_type);

    let form = Form::new()
        .part("metadata", metadata_part)
        .part("content", file_form_part);

    let request_builder =
        RequestBuilder::from_parts(Client::new(), Request::new(Method::POST, url.clone()))
            .multipart(form)
            .headers(new_headers);

    let (client, request) = request_builder.build_split();

    let body_bytes = match request {
        Ok(req) => req.body_mut().map(|b| b.as_bytes()).unwrap_or_default(),
        Err(_) => None,
    };


I need to extract the body and use it as part of a signature to be inserted into the header of the ultimate request that I will send later. I have tried this, but the body always seems to be None in the documentation it says it's None when it's streaming.
My question is if it's streaming, how do I get the body, and if it's not, why is it None?

If you examine the source code of the RequestBuilder::multipart function, you can see that the Form is turned into a stream. To turn the stream into bytes without sending the request, you can take the body, collect it, and add the collected bytes as the new body:
let (_client, request) = request_builder.build_split();
let mut request = request.unwrap();
let body_stream = std::mem::take(request.body_mut()).unwrap();

// Blocking executor works fine when no I/O is
// needed to materialize the stream.
//
// If this required I/O, e.g. files, .await would be better,
// for compatibility and to avoid  blocking an async runtime
// worker thread.
let body_bytes = futures::executor::block_on(
        http_body_util::BodyExt::collect(body_stream)
    )
    .unwrap()
    .to_bytes();

// Access the bytes here.
println!("{:?}", body_bytes);

// Replace the body before sending!
*request.body_mut() = Some(body_bytes.into());


This works thank you very much!

out of curiosity if there was file IO here, what would I need?

Here's a simple python flask server that receives this request
Received request multipart/form-data; boundary=3005de79e0e7d259-5c09ed081d521f8e-7df413d5eeb9e5a9-af6ff9a2efceefc4
 {'metadata': <FileStorage: 'metadata' ('application/json')>, 'content': <FileStorage: 'content' (None)>}

When I

"out of curiosity if there was file IO here, what would I need?" You should then use (...).await instead of futures::executor::block_on(...), to avoid blocking an async runtime worker thread.

"When I..." your comment was cut off. Consider editing your question with additional context, or commenting with a link to the problem.
